# for loop in FreeBSD (pfSense) doesn't work

Tags: bash, freebsd, for, tcsh, pfsense

I've just noticed that the same code for `for loop` in bash doesn't work in FreeBSD

```
wolf@linux:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
wolf@linux:~$ 

wolf@linux:~$ for i in {1..3}; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
wolf@linux:~$
```

Is there any alternative for this?

```
[2.5.0-RELEASE][admin@pfSense]/root: echo $SHELL
/etc/rc.initial
[2.5.0-RELEASE][admin@pfSense]/root: 

[2.5.0-RELEASE][admin@pfSense]/root: for i in {1..3}; do echo $i; done
for: Command not found.
i: Undefined variable.
[2.5.0-RELEASE][admin@pfSense]/root:
```

Comment: I think you're in a `tcsh` shell. Run `sh` to get a more familiar shell (probably not `bash`, and may not understand brace expansions, but would be able to do `for` loops). You could try starting `bash` too, but I have no clue if it's included in the pfsense distribution. This is not a real answer as I have no way of testing it.

Comment: Yeah, `sh` is working, but it can't expand the brace expansions and print it out literally

`# for i in {1,3}; do echo $i; done
{1,3}
# `

Comment: Writing `1 2 3` instead of `{1..3}` requires one less key-press.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with the configuration it is probably better to get used to and learn [pfsense PHP Shell](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/development/php-shell.html)

As @Kusalananda writes: It looks like you are in tcsh. If you want to use bash you need to install it first:

```
pkg install bash
```